# Android TouchEvents DOM API

Tags: android, api, dom

Is there a TouchEvents DOM API for Android?
I need to implement drag & drop behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing Java programs for Android (rather than, say, Web pages with JavaScript for Android), [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) may be what you're looking for.